Binary search 704 leetcode calling a function in python 3
class Solution:
    def search(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        

        #establish a left and right limit
        l = 0
        #this will take from the right and push more towards the middle to // by 2
        r = len(nums) - 1

        #create the mid
        m = (l + r) // 2
#move the mid more towards the right
        if nums[m] > target:
            r = m - 1
        elif nums[m] < target:
            l = m + 1
        else:
            print("-1")


#im calling the function even when i removed the type error I dont think its counting the array and i dont know why
search(0, len(nums = [-1,0,3,5,9,12]),  9)


#error code: TypeError: len() takes no keyword arguments
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   # search(0, len(nums = [-1,0,3,5,9,12]),  9)
#Line 22 in <module> (Solution.py)

I was hoping that calling the function would run the binary search, but calling the function isnt working even when i removed the type error

Where are you instantiating the class Solution?  Please provide all necessary code.

That's all the code

Without an explanation of what you are trying to do, we can't be of much help.  Your assumption we know what Leetcode 704 happens to be about is erroneous.  Also, you say you are calling the function search but this function is a method within the class  Solution but your code doesn't instantiate the Class, so I am not surprised it doesn't run.  Please update your question with information related to what the purpose of your code is as well as show how you are attempting to run this code.

It's a binary search. I'm pretty sure I got it right it's just calling the function that I can't figure out
